# Replace first occurance of a colon with tab

Tags: regex

A line may have 100 colons, but I only want the first colon on each line replaced with a tab.

Example of input data (will differentiate a lot).

```
5b33b9d0a57ff17839bdce76acdd6bcd:::diq23hnjr432ufjn0o0:243r:3rwg:bob@bob.de
5b33b9d0a57ff17839bdce76acdd6bcd:3432rfwediq23hnjr432ufjn0o0:243r:3rwg:bob@bob.de
```

Output I require:

```
5b33b9d0a57ff17839bdce76acdd6bcd    ::diq23hnjr432ufjn0o0:243r:3rwg:bob@bob.de
5b33b9d0a57ff17839bdce76acdd6bcd    3432rfwediq23hnjr432ufjn0o0:243r:3rwg:bob@bob.de
```

I'm simply just looking for a Regex for this, sorry don't have much more to add, can answer any questions, thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^(.*?):(.*)$
Replace: $1\t$2
```

### Demo

Explanation of pattern

```
^
    (.*?)   match and capture everything up until the first :
    :       match a :
    (.*)    match and capture the rest of the line
$
```

Then, we replace with the first and second capture groups, separated by a tab.

Comment: You're a genius, this answer is perfectly fine for me. Seems to wrok great, thankyou!

Comment: Tim, do you need to capture anything after the `:`? If you leave that off and simply replace with `$1\t`, won't that also work?

Comment: @paxdiablo You're right, I overdid it a bit.  Not that my answer is _wrong_, just that we don't really need to capture the second portion.

Comment: Wasn't suggesting it was wrong, it works just fine as is. It's just my OCD nature required me to point out it *could* be simpler. Normal people may have less inclination to do so :-)

Comment: Hey sorry my idiocy, but I'm just wondering how would I modify this Regex so it removes the LAST occurance of a colon with a tab?

Comment: Find: `:([^:]*)$` and Replace: `\t$1`

Comment: This is also highlighting the data after the last colon (which I don't want to happen) only the colon is what I want. Sorry for being a pain lol

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your updated edited comment from 8minutes ago, works great. Thanks again your a genius

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your regex engine (unfortunately, there's not *one* regex engine that's used *everywhere*). Probably the most *portable* solution is something along the lines of:

```
s/^\([^:]*\):/\1\t/
```

This uses the search pattern:

```
^             - start of line.
\( ... \)     - capture group.
[^:]          - character class meaning everything that's not a colon.
*             - zero or more occurences of.
:             - a literal colon.
```

meaning everything up to the *first* colon, ensuring we capture everything but that colon for later use.

The replacement `\1\t` is simply the thing we captured (everything before the first colon) followed by a tab character.

The effect is basically what you needed, repacing the first colon in the line with a tab.

Just keep in mind the "there's not *one* regex engine" comment of mine above, you may need to adjust escape characters and or special characters based on the regex engine you're using.

This particular one works in a large number of engines, even the notoriously deficient `sed` one:

```
>> echo 'This is : hello : an example' | sed 's/^\([^:]*\):/\1\t/'
This is          hello : an example
```

---

Of course, if you're using a tool (like `sed`) that has the option to only replace the first occurrence on each line, you should probably use that so you don't have to mess around with capture groups:

```
>> echo 'This is : hello : an example' | sed 's/:/\t/'
This is          hello : an example
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change values only upto the first `:`, you can simply match value upto the first `:` colon and then use back reference to captured group and replace it with `$1\t` to get desired output 
You can use

```
/^([^:]*):/
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `([^:]*)` - Match anything except `:` zero or more time
- `:` - Match `:`

Replace by `$1\t`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Olo0sv/3/)

***Side note:-*** If you want atleast one character should be there before `:` than you can change quantifier from `*` to `+`

Comment: One more quickie, I think you may need a capture group to stop the colon coming into the substitution. As is stands now, it seems to *insert* a tab after the first colon rather than replacing it.

Comment: @paxdiablo mybad, i got confused with first desired output, updated, thanks mate :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but lookahead do not capture character so it will still persist

Comment: You're right +1, what you gave is probably the leanest way to do this.